# Is it possible to use both JAXB and Simple XML?

Tags: android, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I'm writing an API client library for Android and I've used Simple XML to deserialize the objects since it seems JAXB doesn't work on Android.

The classes in the API project have XML annotations for JAXB. I copied the classes to my Android library but changed the XML annotations for Simple XML. Obviously, this will create a problem syncing changes.

Is there anyway to make the two compatible so that the same code can be used with JAXB and Simple XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I see as possible is using **both annotation types at the same time**. You can mark each member field with JAXB and SimpleXML annotations. Of course you need some glue to get this working and make the compiler not complain about inexistent annotations. To get rid of this you can write your own annotation library implementing the missing annotations in every case (JAXB annotations on Android and SimpleXML on other projects) doing what is expected (nothing).

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! I'm going to make two separate libraries, one with fake JAXB annotations and one with fake SimpleXML annotations. It would be better if I could combine them into the same library, but I can't figure out how to do a factory pattern with interfaces whose source can't be modified (I don't want to change the XML framework libs). Thought about loading the classes dynamically but class loading seems to differ between Java and Android and I'm not sure if that strategy will work with annotations. Thanks again!

Comment: @marchica: Did you get "making two separate libraries with fake annotations" working? As far as I know, on Android it is not possible for an external library to implement most common libraries in the java.* and javax.* namespaces (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13084 for details).

If you could get both of these libraries working together, could you please post an answer here so that we can all benefit?